# When making a node query, will react-relay check if that node is in the store before making a network request?

Tags: relayjs, relay, relaymodern, react-relay

If I create a graphql server that has the following schema:

```
type Node {
   id: ID!
}
type User implements Node {
   id: ID!
   groups: [group!]!
}

type Group implements Node {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
   me: User!
   node(id: ID!): Node
}
```

Later using react-relay I make the following query:

```
query {
  me {
    groups {
        id
        name
    }
  }
}
```

which returns the following

```
{
    me: {
        groups: [{
            id: '1',
            name: 'food lovers'
        }]
    }
}
```

if later on in my application I make another query as follows

```
query  {
    node(id: "1") {
        ... on Group {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}
```

will react-relay make a request to the server? or is it smart enough to know that we already have all the data for the requested item in our cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://relay.dev/docs/en/query-renderer) the default behavior `network-only` is not to use the cache and instead always fetch fresh results from the server. You can change this setting by specifying a `fetchPolicy` of `store-and-network` which will first use cached results and in parallel fetch fresh data from the network.

It is also important to know, that relay does [garbage collection](https://relay.dev/docs/en/runtime-architecture) on it's store, so records that aren't referenced will be removed from the "cache" eventually.

The documentation for relay's **experimental** features indicates that there will be a [`store-only`](https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/a-guided-tour-of-relay#fetch-policies) option and APIs to [manually retain data](https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/a-guided-tour-of-relay#garbage-collection-in-relay) in the cache, as well as ways to [render partial data](https://relay.dev/docs/en/experimental/a-guided-tour-of-relay#rendering-partially-cached-data-highly-experimental), while waiting for the network.